# Lex: Longest Word Consisting Only of Letters from Other Word

Tags: c, lex, flex-lexer

I am trying to write lex code which will take a string as input, and parse through a long dictionary file to find the longest word in that dictionary which is made up of only the letters in that string. Each letter in the string can be used zero or more times, meaning the word "in" would be valid for "input". Here is what I have so far:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%option noyywrap

%% 
[input]+ { 
          printf("This is the longest I think: %s\n", yytext);
         }

.|\n    {}
%%

int main(void)
{
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

However, this really does not do what I expect it to do. This code goes through and prints the matching portions of every word in the dictionary, so I get output like "i", "iu", "inu", etc., and these obviously aren't valid words. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This sounds like trying to use a hammer to screw in a screw -- lex is for recognizing tokens in an input stream, not for searching through a dictionary or finding permutations...

Comment: What you are doing is to look at words made up of the letters `inptu` only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the beginning-of-line and end-of-line markers as part of your regular expression to require that the entire line is matched, not just a part of it.  Try changing your regex from `[input]+` to

```
^[input]+$
```

You will then need some separate logic to track the longest string you've found so far, but judging from the code you have above I think this more directly addresses your question at hand.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer, but I left out a very important part in my question by mistake. Each letter in the string can be used zero or more times, meaning the word "in" would be valid for "input". Can you help me with this additional constraint?

Comment: @JohnRoberts- I think the above regular expression would match the word "in".  The regex `[input]+` means "any word that can be formed from 1 or more copies of the letters i, n, p, u, and t.  Or am I misinterpreting your statement?

Comment: Yes, you're right - never mind. I had a typo in my code. Thanks.

Comment: I've got another if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667484/lex-finding-first-permutation-of-input-word